# Get obtain a list of mutually connected nodes between every pair of directly connected nodes in R

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I want to obtain a list of mutually connected nodes between every pair of directly connected nodes in my graph:

My data looks like below:

```
countryA <- c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "GERMANY", "GERMANY", "GERMANY", "JAPAN", "JAPAN", "CHINA", "USA", "USA", "FRANCE")

countryB <- c("MEXICO", "CANADA", "GERMANY", "JAPAN", "CANADA", "JAPAN", "FRANCE", "KOREA", "CHINA", "KOREA", "KOREA",  "CHINA", "CANADA")

year <- (c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000))
data <- data.frame(countryA, countryB, year)
data$countryA <- as.character(data$countryA)
data$countryB <- as.character(data$countryB)

edge <- graph_from_data_frame(data, directed = FALSE)

plot(edge)
```

[image]

In this graph, for instance, USA and Japan share common nodes China, Korea, and Germany.

I would like to build a data frame like below:

either (1)

```
node1    node2      mutual
USA      Japan      Korea, China
Japan    USA        Korea, China
USA      Germany    Canada
Germany  USA.       Canada
Korea    Japan      USA, China
Japan    Korea      USA, China
Korea    China      Japan
China    Korea      Japan    
China    Japan      Korea, USA
Japan    China      Korea, USA
France   Germany    Canada
Germany  France    Canada
France   Canada    Germany
Canada   France    Germany
```

or (2)

```
node1    node2      mutual
USA      Japan      Korea
USA      Japan      China
Japan    USA        Korea
Japan    USA        China
USA      Germany    Canada
Germany  USA        Canada
Korea    Japan      USA
Korea    Japan      China
Japan    Korea      USA
Japan    Korea      China
Korea    China      Japan
China    Korea      Japan
China    Japan      Korea
Japan    China      Korea
Japan    China      USA
China    Japan      USA
France   Germany    Canada
Germany  France     Canada
France   Canada    Germany
Canada   France    Germany
```

I've tried the code below

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  apply(
    matrix(triangles(G), nrow = 3),
    2,
    function(v) {
      u <- t(sapply(seq_along(v), function(k) t(v[-k])))
      setNames(data.frame(cbind(v, rbind(u, u[, 2:1]))), c("node1", "node2", "mutual"))
    }
  )
)
```

This code is credited to @ThomasIsCoding's comments in the link: [Return a list of mutual nodes between every pair of nodes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127621/return-a-list-of-mutual-nodes-between-every-pair-of-nodes-in-r)

Or

```
get_mutuals <- function(g) {
  do.call("rbind", lapply(seq.int(1, vcount(g)-1), function(i) {
    do.call("rbind", lapply(seq.int(i+1, vcount(g)), function(j) {
      ni <- neighbors(g, i)
      nj <- neighbors(g, j)
      overlap <- intersect(ni, nj)
      if (length(overlap) & i %in% nj) {
        data.frame(i=i, j=j, m=overlap)
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    }))
  }))
}
get_mutuals(G)
```

This code is credited to @MrFlick.

Those codes work fine when I worked with
the below data but when I tried to work with the data above, it gives out numerics as a node id instead of country names.

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph(c(1,2,1,3,1,4,2,4, 2,3,2,5,3,5,4,5,5,6,5,7,7,8,7,9), directed=F)
 
plot(G)
```

[image: Click here for the Graph]

```
 node1   node2     mutual
   1      2          3
   1      2          4
   1      3          2
   1      4          2
   2      3          1
   2      3          5
```

I believe that the reason is different structure of the data. But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  apply(
    matrix(names(triangles(edge)), nrow = 3),
    2,
    function(v) {
      u <- t(sapply(seq_along(v), function(k) t(v[-k])))
      setNames(data.frame(cbind(v, rbind(u, u[, 2:1]))), c("node1", "node2", "mutual"))
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
     node1   node2  mutual
1      USA GERMANY  CANADA
2  GERMANY     USA  CANADA
3   CANADA     USA GERMANY
4      USA  CANADA GERMANY
5  GERMANY  CANADA     USA
6   CANADA GERMANY     USA
7      USA GERMANY   JAPAN
8  GERMANY     USA   JAPAN
9    JAPAN     USA GERMANY
10     USA   JAPAN GERMANY
11 GERMANY   JAPAN     USA
12   JAPAN GERMANY     USA
13     USA   JAPAN   KOREA
14   JAPAN     USA   KOREA
15   KOREA     USA   JAPAN
16     USA   KOREA   JAPAN
17   JAPAN   KOREA     USA
18   KOREA   JAPAN     USA
19     USA   JAPAN   CHINA
20   JAPAN     USA   CHINA
21   CHINA     USA   JAPAN
22     USA   CHINA   JAPAN
23   JAPAN   CHINA     USA
24   CHINA   JAPAN     USA
25     USA   CHINA   KOREA
26   CHINA     USA   KOREA
27   KOREA     USA   CHINA
28     USA   KOREA   CHINA
29   CHINA   KOREA     USA
30   KOREA   CHINA     USA
31 GERMANY  CANADA  FRANCE
32  CANADA GERMANY  FRANCE
33  FRANCE GERMANY  CANADA
34 GERMANY  FRANCE  CANADA
35  CANADA  FRANCE GERMANY
36  FRANCE  CANADA GERMANY
37   JAPAN   CHINA   KOREA
38   CHINA   JAPAN   KOREA
39   KOREA   JAPAN   CHINA
40   JAPAN   KOREA   CHINA
41   CHINA   KOREA   JAPAN
42   KOREA   CHINA   JAPAN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just re-associate the numerical ids with the names afterward:

```
df <- get_mutuals(edge)

names <- as_ids(V(edge))

for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  df[,i] <- names[df[,i]]
}
```

```
> head(df, 5)
    i       j       m
1 USA GERMANY   JAPAN
2 USA GERMANY  CANADA
3 USA   JAPAN GERMANY
4 USA   JAPAN   CHINA
5 USA   JAPAN   KOREA
```